# Restrict the size of message in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: mqtt, activemq-artemis

I want to restrict the size of message to 800 KB for users trying to publish mqtt message in the artemis topic and for that I have updated address-settings in theetc/broker.xml with

```
<max-size-bytes>800</max-size-bytes>
<page-size-bytes>800</page-size-bytes>
```

This seems not working and I am able to publish 1 MB message through MQTT client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max-size-bytes` setting applies to an *address*, not a message. Also, this setting without notation is interpreted as bytes (although other byte notations can be used, e.g. `MB`, `kb`, etc.). Therefore, setting `<max-size-bytes>800</max-size-bytes>` will tell the broker to enforce the corresponding `address-full-policy` (which is `PAGE` by default) when the total number of bytes in the matching address is `800`. As [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/paging.html#configuration) states, `max-size-bytes` is:

> ...the max memory the address could have before entering on page mode.

Several different policies/modes are supported here. Aside from `PAGE` the broker supports `FAIL`, `DROP`, and `BLOCK`. See [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/paging.html) for more details on these.

If you want to exclude messages based strictly on their size I recommend you implement an MQTT [interceptor](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/intercepting-operations.html). Ensure you're using at least 2.12.0 so that you have the fix for [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2607).

Comment: This is awesome, Interceptor worked in my case. Is there any way to pass runtime argument in the interceptor ? In my case, I want to keep the size of message configurable which Interceptor will exclude if its exceeds.

Comment: You can define Java system properties (e.g. in `etc/artemis.profile`) and then retrieve those values in your interceptor.